# XML result of SOLR

Tags: xml, solr

I am going to use the XML result of Solr search server, does any body know how I can use get it or where it is saved?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest installing Solr and trying out the examples. This will give you a feel for how the technology works.

Comment: If your interested in GUIs generated from Solr search results check out ajax-solr: https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are going to use XML results so please dont save them somewhere as an extra I/O would be involved in that case.

Answer to your question depends on the programming language/environment you are using.

For an example, if you are using Python then there is a urllib module which can help you out.

Something like (code snippet):

```
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom
dom = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen("http://localhost:8080/sor/select/...."))
```

Now your variable 'dom' will have XML returned & you can do the processing.

So you can search for similar stuff in the programming language you are using for processing solr xml.

Comment: what about c#? I wamt to use the data im asp page.